# Yii - Modifing html generated by CListView

Tags: yii

I'm using ClistView to display the content of a dataprovider.

ClistView is supposed to call a partial view, that will loop for each model.

I would like to display something (i.e. a  tag) before the first model and something (i.e. a ) after the last model of the pagination.

Assume that I have a view (index.php):

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
                    'dataProvider'=>$localDataProvider,
                    'itemView'=>'_view',   // refers to the partial view named '_post'
                    'summaryText'=>'Sono visualizzati i record da {start} a {end} su un totale di {count} libri',
                    'pager' => Array(
                    'header' => 'Vai alla pagina',
                    'prevPageLabel' => 'Indietro',
                    'nextPageLabel' => 'Avanti',
                    ),
                    ));
```

In _view.php I have just the cells of a table.

If I put before the widget the html to render the table header and just after the html to render the table footer I obtain that inside the div there is the html of the pager.

How I can shift the header and the footer directly in _view.php?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this class extension:

```
Yii::import('zii.widgets.CListView');

class PlainCListView extends CListView

{

public $preItemsTag = '';
public $postItemsTag = '';

public function renderItems()
{
    echo $this->preItemsTag."\n";
    $data=$this->dataProvider->getData();
    if(($n=count($data))>0)
    {
        $owner=$this->getOwner();
        $render=$owner instanceof CController ? 'renderPartial' : 'render';
        $j=0;
        foreach($data as $i=>$item)
        {
            $data=$this->viewData;
            $data['index']=$i;
            $data['data']=$item;
            $data['widget']=$this;
            $owner->$render($this->itemView,$data);
            if($j++ < $n-1)
                echo $this->separator;
        }
    }
    else
        $this->renderEmptyText();
    echo $this->postItemsTag."\n";

}


 }
```

I's possible to override the lines of the base version of the class

```
echo CHtml::openTag($this->itemsTagName,array('class'=>$this->itemsCssClass))."\n";

echo CHtml::closeTag($this->itemsTagName);
```

With this solution with code:

```
$pre_html = '<table><thead><th>Codice Account</th><th>Nome</th></thead><tbody>';
$post_html = '</tbody></table>';

$this->widget('zii.widgets.PlainCListView', array(
                    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
                    'itemView'=>'_view', 
                    'preItemsTag'=>$pre_html,
                    'postItemsTag'=>$post_html,
                    'summaryText'=>'Sono visualizzati i record da {start} a {end} su un totale di {count} libri',
                    'pager' => Array(
                    'header' => 'Vai alla pagina',
                    'prevPageLabel' => 'Indietro',
                    'nextPageLabel' => 'Avanti',
                        ),
                    'sortableAttributes'=>array('titolo'),
                    'enableSorting'=>0,



));
```

It's possible to get in the output what I need.

Comment: @maxdnangelo: where have you placed : "PlainCListView" class file ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to generate a table, you should be trying to do it using CGridView instead of CListView.

Comment: Nahian, thanks for your answer. Of course if I use CGridView I don't have any issue, but I would like to use ClistView to get what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the template for the CClistView as

```
'template'   => "<your header tag>{items}<your footer tag>{pager}",
```

you might arrange the template stuff as you need.

Comment: Thanks again, but this is not helping, there is too much html not requested. I modified the CListView Class.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "I modified CListView class" but I recommend what I think is more accurate - *extend* CListView, do your modifications in the extending class, and use that class. Do not change the framework's class. That bad practice. Among the rest, doing so in more similar situations will prevent you from upgrading your framework folder, for new security updates fixes, for example.

Comment: Boaz, thanks for the suggestion. It's clear that with I modified I was meaning I extended. Modifing the framework is a bad practice.