# Custom CListView in Yii framework

Tags: php, yii, widget

I wanted to modify the default list view provided by the Yii framework. The current view display everything as a row [image]. What I want is to display the information in following format[image]. Could you suggest me how can I extend this widget and create my own view. I have attached both needed as a image. I am new to Yii so all help would be really appriciable. If there is already any widget in this format I would be so happy.

Content for my view File would be

```
    <?php
/* @var $this LeosafealertController */
/* @var $data Leosafealert */
?>

<div class="view">  
    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('id')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->id), array('view', 'id'=>$data->id)); ?>
        <br/>
    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('date')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::encode($data->date); ?>
        <br/>
    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('description')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::encode($data->description); ?>
        <br/>
    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('photo')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::image($data->getImageURL().$data->photo,$data->photo); ?>
        </br>
        <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('link')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode("click here"), $data->getFileURL().$data->link,array('target'=>'_blank')); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831685/yii-modifing-html-generated-by-clistview

Comment: Thanks for that, but can we achieve that by modifying the widget, because I may want to use it at some other places as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not edit your view file (e.g. just edit '/path/to/model/views/_view.php', or whatever your view file is called)?

You can also declare your own css file for a CLitView by defining a [cssFile](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView#cssFile-detail) property. ie;

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
    'cssFile'=>'/css/myCssFile.css',
    ...
));
```

You could create your own css file for your layout and use that for every CListView you want with the given layout?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Stu, My problem is I do not have much experience in CSS could you suggest me the sample code for that CSS

Comment: can you add the contents of your view file to your question? As the css needed will vary wildly depending on how your view file is laid out ;)